# Lotus Connections get all users following discussion

Tags: rss, lotus

Does anyone know a good way to get all of the users who are following a specific discussion in lotusconnections? I havent been able to find this functionality in the IBM documentation at all.

Answer (score 0):

If by discussion you mean a Forum topic, looks like this was asked and answered here [IBM Connections - get all followers of a Forum topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359422/ibm-connections-get-all-followers-of-a-forum-topic)