# IBM Connections - get all followers of a Forum topic

Tags: api, lotus, ibm-connections

I am attempting to send emails to all of the users currently following a topic when a reply is posted in IBM Connections. In IBM's API I can find how to assign a user to follow a forum topic but I do not see any way to retrieve a list of all the users that are currently following a specific topic. Does anyone know if this kind of functionality exists?

Comment: What do you mean by "topic"? A thread in a forum?

Comment: yes sorry, by topic I meant a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that information is not available via the API.

You can get a list of the resources followed by the *authenticated user* via the [Following API](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Following_API_ic45&content=pdcontent), but that does not work for any other users (I assume due to privacy issues).

You could fetch it the info you are looking for from the database via SQL statements, but that is not officially supported, as the databases could/will change with every product update. In the [IBM Connections Forum at developerworks](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcforum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/acc608957638edff852579a5003cdb73?OpenDocument), there is an example for Communities.

Comment: thanks, thats what i thought but was hoping there was a well known way to get all the followers. Dont think im going with the sql route because of possible db changes.